# The property of complexity class P

Tags: algorithm, class, complexity-theory

I'm reading the book <<Introduction to Algorithms>>, third edition.  There is a proof to theorem 34.2 (Page 1059):

> **Because the class of languages decided by polynomial-time algorithms is a subset of the class of languages accepted by polynomial-time
>   algorithms**, we need only show that if L is accepted by a
>   polynomial-time algorithm, it is decided by a polynomial-time
>   algorithm.  Let L be the language **accepted** by some polynomial-time
>   algorithm A...(the proof is omitted)...and thus A is a polynomial-time
>   algorithm that **decides** L.

I think that is mean that there if there are two sets A and B, and A is the subset of B, and an element x∈A, this proves x∈B.

In addition, I understand that "the class of languages decided by polynomial-time algorithms is a subset of the class of languages accepted by polynomial-time algorithms".  So this proof confuses me...

Comment: The proof was omitted from the book, because it's an Intro, at this level, even the theory is difficult for you to understand at this point

Comment: Could you explain this please "the class of languages decided by polynomial-time algorithms is a subset of the class of languages accepted by polynomial-time algorithms." Shouldn't they be the same/equal?

Answer (score 0):

> In computational complexity theory, P, also known as PTIME or
>   DTIME(n^O(1)), is one of the most fundamental complexity classes. It
>   contains all decision problems which can be solved by a deterministic
>   Turing machine using a polynomial amount of computation time, or
>   polynomial time.

Source: [Wikipedia:P(Complexity)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%28complexity%29)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Here, he wants to show that A = B (accepted = decided). From the definition, 'decided' means that the machine always stops with the correct answer 'yes' or 'no' within a polynomial time, while 'accepted' means that the machine stops with the correct answer within a polynomial time, when the correct answer is 'yes'; when the correct answer is 'no', it can loop forever or answer 'no'. Clearly this second condition is less stringent, hence it is obvious that 'decided' implies 'accepted', B is included in A. The proof is thus mainly about the other direction, A is included in B. Here he uses the time bound to construct a machine that always halts. This constructions works for all time-bounded classes, provided the overhead of counting and bounding time stays is the class.